# Assign value to State object key of another key's value in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to check whether sum of three numbers is equal if yes then i want to update the state.

```
state = {
    number1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    number2 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    number3 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    proposedAnswer : Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + this.number1 + this.number2 + this.number3
}
```

But when i try to use `{this.state.proposedAnswer}` i will get NAN ?
Any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to a property of an object before initializing it... perhaps something like this would work in your case?

```js
let number1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
let number2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
let number3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

this.state = {
    number1,
    number2,
    number3,
    proposedAnswer : Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + number1 + number2 + number3
}

console.log(this.state);
```

Comment: Thanks Man , now it is working ! thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that you that not accessing those variables by state. Instead you should do this:

```
state = {
    number1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    number2 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    number3 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    proposedAnswer : ''
}
```

Since the state is initialized, now we can define a function to calculate the sum.

```
sum = () => {
  this.setState ({
    proposedAnswer:  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + this.state.number1 + this.state.number2 + this.state.number3
  )}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I believe all of the `this.state.numberX` properties would be undefined since the object has not been initialized yet.

Comment: Doesn't work, indeeds fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'number1' of undefined`

Comment: @NinoFiliu,It was my mistake. Now the code has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in your code does not refer to anything, so you are summing `undefined` to a number and then get `NaN`.

You could use the callback version of setState in which you pass a function which takes a state and return a new state.
Inside a PureComponent you can write this function so that if some test is true you return the old state.

```
this.setState((state) => {
  const number1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  const number2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  const number3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  const proposedAnswer : Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + number1 + number2 + number3

  if (proposedAnswer ...) {
    // return a new state
  }
  // in the default case you return the old state unchanged
  return state;
})
```

Note that I would not recommend this pattern as your update function is not a `pure function`. If you can add any detail as to your current use case maybe I can elaborate on which pattern could be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your state inside setState method.
Here is a sample-

```
state = {
    number1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    number2 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    number3 : Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    proposedAnswer: ''
}

calculateSum = () => {
  this.setState ({
    proposedAnswer:  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + this.state.number1 + this.state.number2 + this.state.number3
 )}
 console.log(state);
}
```

You can call the calculateSum method inside your render method for any input text or div. Let me know if this helps.